# Collision between shared data

Tags: php

This is a common problem about sharing data.

As i am building a system that allow user share their mailing list to their colleague.

I suspect there is a problem when userA open the page , 
userB open the same page and edit the data, 
after that user A edit the data and submit and the changes of userB will be cancel.

As i am using PHP , is their any way to prevent this kind of error???  Thank you.|

Are there any coding example provided in php /jquery??? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make editions log, so user A will update conent ver. 123 to ver. 124 , user B will try too to update ver. 123 in his own way, but on server there is already ver. 124, so you will show message to user B, that content was recently modified by another user.

This principe is used in SVN for example.

Comment: Wikipedia (and other wikis) work this way, too. Merging can be tricky, though.

Comment: Example is hard to make, because it is change to data model and to code

Answer (score 0):

There are a few solutions.
The simplest would be to have a "lock" field on a database which is set to true when someone is looking at a page, and refuses to let anyone else enter the page while it is locked. This isn't a great idea because it's difficult to capture when someone has left the page, so the page might remain locked forever.

You can get around that problem by using a little AJAX call that sends a message to the server to lock the page every ten seconds or so, and the page locking has a thirty-second time limit.

Perhaps the best method (although this depends on the system) is to use AJAX to dynamically reload components of the page when they are edited by another user (and to put a message next to them when they are *being* edited), and to warn both users if they are editing the same field at the same time.

Comment: I think in my system i don't have to implement like the wiki level? Since that is just a mail list with few fields.